# Not getting Wordpress confirmation mail for change of default email address

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to change the default wordpress email in Settings>General but not getting the confirmation email if I enter an email address of my own domain.

For eg:
My wordpress site is www.mydomain.com

If I change the email to info@mydomain.com I dont get any confirmation mail for applying the change. But if i change the email to myname@gmail.com then I get the confirmation mail.

My Wordpress site is hosted at ecowebhosting.co.uk and my domain email is configured in google G-suite.
I have purchased domain from Bigrock.in

I dont know if that is creating any problem

If anyone can please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it from database:

> ->Login to your database
>
> ->go to users table
>   ->search for admin
>   ->open admin and look for email address
>   ->change the email address and save it

Answer (score 3):

Here's an easier way:

Step 1: Log in to your WordPress with your admin account.
Step 2: Click on Settings - General
Step 3: Change the URL from options-general.php to just options.php
Step 4: Find the admin email field, change it, and save it.
Done!

Comment: Hey, could you elaborate on how to do this? I cant find the options-general.php